# Certain sites not working in Firefox, working in IE

Tags: windows, firefox, internet, windows-explorer

Totally weird thing happening on my PC after I came back from the Holiday shutdown.

My homepage by default is google.com/ig but when it opens (in Firefox) the G-Mail panel does not display and eventually times out.  I then try to navigate to https://www.gmail.com but that also times out.  Thinking maybe work decided to drop the ban-hammer on g-mail I decided to try it in Internet Explorer.  Oddly enough it works in IE

Any idea on why it works fine in one browser but not the other?

Comment: Could be proxy settings.

Comment: Work has updated their no-no list

Comment: I checked the proxy settings and they are identical for both IE & Firefox.  Also, @Random it works in I.E but not Firefox.  I could see it not working in both , but seems odd that it works in one & not the other

Answer (score 2):

Configuration needed some adjustments - Apparently there were some changes in the network so I needed to set up a proxy for https connections.

There is a checkbox in the advanced settings to use the proxy for all connection types.  That fixed it!